# Javascript IE Issue

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

This is a code for a WYSIWYG text editor I am working on. I'm working on the HTML to BBCODE and vice versa part now. It works fine in Fire Fox but not in Internet Explorer. Thoughts?

```
function textstyle(a) {
    document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.focus();
}

function option(a,b) {
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand(a, false, b);
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.focus();
}

function button(a) {
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand(a, false, null);
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.focus();
}

var colorSelection;

function selectColor(selection) {
    colorSelection = selection;
    document.getElementById('colorSelector').style.left = 0 + document.getElementById(selection).offsetLeft + "px";
    document.getElementById('colorSelector').style.top = 0 + document.getElementById(selection).offsetTop + document.getElementById(selection).offsetHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById('colorSelector').style.visibility = 'visible';
    return;
}

function changeColor(colorCode) {
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand(colorSelection, false, colorCode);
    document.getElementById('colorSelector').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.focus();
    return;
}

function dismissmenu()
{
    document.getElementById("colorSelector").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("fontlist").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("formatlist").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("sizelist").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function Start() {
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, "false");

    try {
        document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand("undo", false, null);
        editormode = "true";
    }  catch (e) {
        editormode = "false";
    }

    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
        document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document.addEventListener("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
        document.addEventListener("keypress", dismissmenu, true);
        document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document.addEventListener("keypress", dismissmenu, true);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
        document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document.attachEvent("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
        document.attachEvent("keypress", dismissmenu, true);
        document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document.attachEvent("keypress", dismissmenu, true);
    }
}

function switchEditorMode() {
    if (editormode == "true") {

        var replaceTagsByMode = function(html, editormode) {
            var tags = {};
            for (var i=0, a=['b', 'i', 'u', 'strike', 'sub', 'sup']; i<a.length; i++) {
                tags[['<', a[i], '>'].join('')] = ['[', a[i], ']'].join('');
                tags[['</', a[i], '>'].join('')] = ['[/', a[i], ']'].join('');
            }
            for (var html_tag in tags) {
                if (tags.hasOwnProperty(html_tag)) {
                    html = html.replace.apply(
                    html, editormode ? [html_tag, tags[html_tag], 'g'] : [tags[html_tag], html_tag, 'g']);
                }
            }
            return html;
        };

        var editor_body = document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.body;
        editor_body.innerHTML = replaceTagsByMode(editor_body.innerHTML, editormode);


        editormode = "false";

    } else {

        var replaceTagsByMode = function(html, editormode) {
            var tags = {};
            for (var i=0, a=['b', 'i', 'u', 'strike', 'sub', 'sup']; i<a.length; i++) {
                tags[['[', a[i], ']'].join('')] = ['<', a[i], '>'].join('');
                tags[['[/', a[i], ']'].join('')] = ['</', a[i], '>'].join('');
            }
            for (var html_tag in tags) {
                if (tags.hasOwnProperty(html_tag)) {
                    html = html.replace.apply(
                    html, editormode ? [html_tag, tags[html_tag], 'g'] : [tags[html_tag], html_tag, 'g']);
                }
            }
            return html;
        };

        var editor_body = document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.body;
        editor_body.innerHTML = replaceTagsByMode(editor_body.innerHTML, editormode);


        editormode = "true";

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: Thought I might add. I am VERY new to JavaScript. Other than what you see here I've never done any JS work before, though I do HTML, CSS, PHP, MySQL.

Comment: @EndangeredMassa, When I press the button for the editor to toggle from WYSIWYG mode to BBCODE it doesn't convert. Nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have script error reporting on for IE? (It will show you an error in a popup). Or are you using the IE Dev tools? that will show errors in the log on the right of the script panel. Most likely, it's producing a JS error in IE. IE is very touchy about syntax and FF/Chrome/Safari is fine with, and it also doesn't support all the same methods for DOM objects, as you may know.

Comment: The question is not descriptive as to what is going on. The poster has just dumped the entire javascript code here. No attempt to narrow down the problem seems to have been made. upvotes? for what?

Comment: @AlexJL There isn't a popup normally but shows error icon bottom left of browser and I can click for information. The lines that do things like this give errors:
document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, "false");

Comment: It says it is an invalid arguement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just passing thru with similar issues, but noticed this:

```
document.attachEvent("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
```

should be like this I think for '.attachEvent':

```
document.attachEvent("onmouseup", dismissmenu, true);
```

I know one or the other event attachment methods use the 'on' part directly. I believe it is IE that does. Plus, some events work better attached to the 'body' element, as opposed to the document. I use the Dojo toolkit and dojo.connect() function for normal event setting and attach onclick, etc. events to the body element. The toolkit helps with differences in syntax like above. Keeps issues like this out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments you note this:

> The lines that do things like this
> give errors:
>
> document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand("styleWithCSS",
> false, "false");
>
> It says it is an invalid argument.

That could be because styleWithCSS is not a valid Command Identifier for execCommand :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049%28v=VS.85%29.aspx